# How to create valid XML

Tags: xml, linq

I need to create a valid XML format based on few combinations.
Below is the requirement.
There are three dropdownlists:

1. BusinessFunction

   - Contract
   - FullTime
   - PartTime
2. WorkpacketType

   - Warranty
   - Period
3. Activity

   - Cancel
   - Amend
   - Update

Based on any drop down value there is validation applied on UI for `TextBox`. Suppose if business-function contract is selected ,textbox1 should be made mandatory
or if businessfunction contract and workpackettype warranty is selected then textbox2 should be made mandatory

All these validations are required to be defined in xml format

I had tried many combinations but i am not able to put in valid combinations in XML which will give me proper output.

Please guide me how should I put my validations in proper XML format.
The application is in MVC and we are reading validations using C# method with LINQ queries on above XML.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear to me what the problem is. Are you stuck trying to work out what the XML document should look like, or writing the code to use it?

Comment: Can you show us what you have already tried?

Comment: Hello all I am trying to make xml in a proper way as per the selection made using drop-down values..I am clear with c# code but I am not able to put those conditions in proper xml format..

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the

> [System.Xml.Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq?view=netframework-4.7.2)

namespace and the [XDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=netframework-4.7.2), [XElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [XAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) which according to me should give you the proper results you want.

Give it a try and if something is not clear, tell us what issues you are facing.

**Here is an example taken from the above docs:**

```
XDocument srcTree = new XDocument(  
new XComment("This is a comment"),  
new XElement("Root",  
    new XElement("Child1", "data1"),  
    new XElement("Child2", "data2"),  
    new XElement("Child3", "data3"),  
    new XElement("Child2", "data4"),  
    new XElement("Info5", "info5"),  
    new XElement("Info6", "info6"),  
    new XElement("Info7", "info7"),  
    new XElement("Info8", "info8")  
 )  
);  

XDocument doc = new XDocument(  
    new XComment("This is a comment"),  
    new XElement("Root",  
        from el in srcTree.Element("Root").Elements()  
        where ((string)el).StartsWith("data")  
        select el  
    )  
);
```

Comment: @vaibhavi mokal, has my answer helped you in anyway?